# Get Result of Trigger Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table with 3 columns: `id uniqueidentifier, rowversion bigint, data int`

Sometimes a data value will be updated. When that happens I want to increment the rowversion. I have done this using a sequence called `My_Table_RowVersion_Seq` and the following trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[My_Table_UPDATE] ON [dbo].[My_Table]
FOR UPDATE AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


UPDATE [dbo].[My_Table] SET [dbo].[My_Table].[RowVersion] = NEXT VALUE
FOR dbo.My_Table_RowVersion_Seq
FROM INSERTED [updateData]
WHERE [updateData].[ID]=[dbo].[My_Table].[ID] END;
```

The trigger and sequence are working correctly. When I update a row's data column the `rowversion` is changed. However, I have been trying to read out the new `rowversion` value using the `OUTPUT` and `INPUT` clauses and that is not working. I seem to always get the previous value (the value before the update).

Here is the `UPDATE` query I am using:

```
DECLARE @OutputTempTable TABLE (updatedversion bigint);
UPDATE My_Table SET data=12 OUTPUT Inserted.RowVersion INTO @OutputTempTable WHERE Id = '368B4035-3E8E-4AB3-8D7A-DCA6332AE718';
SELECT * FROM @OutputTempTable
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) for `OUTPUT` I can see that the `OUTPUT` data is collected before the trigger fires. How do you then get the final state of the row? Do you have to read it back out 'manually'? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you might need to read it back manually.